# how to give parameters when connecting to different webpages in django framework

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-templates

I'm trying to link two webpages in django framework, using anchor tags in template. One of my view takes an argument and I can't figure out how to pass a parameter in template.
This is a url pattern that takes argument.

`path("<str:entry>",views.display_entry,name="entry")`

corresponding view is:

```
def display_entry(request,entry):

    text = str(util.get_entry(entry))
    markdown = Markdown()
    html = markdown.convert(text)
    html_file = open(f"encyclopedia/templates/encyclopedia/{entry}.html",'w')
    html_file.write(html)
    html_file.close()

    return render(request, f"encyclopedia/{entry}.html")
```

and template where I'm trying to access this view is -

```
<ul>
        {% for entry in entries %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'encyclopedia/entry' %}">{{ entry }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
path("<str:entry>", views.display_entry, name="entry-detail")

{% for entry in entries %}
    <a href="{% url 'entry-detail' entry %}">{{ entry }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```